# Where add 64K code and where?

Tags: android

What code must i add and where to get 64K methods?

I try and build signed APK but it give me issue whole time!

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ’:myapp:transformClassesWithDexForRelease’. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KUMAR's answer is pretty close but not covering all the details.

**Firstly add necessary configuration to your build.gradle of app module:**

> app/build.gradle

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
}

dependencies 
{
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

---

**In the second step you can follow two paths depending on your need.**

*a. You don't have a custom application class. So you need to add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element in your manifest:*

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

OR

*b. You have a custom application class. So you need to make it extend MultiDexApplication class:*

> MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name="MyApplication"
```

---

You should be ready to go over 64K method limit.

You can read [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) over multidex to understand the logic behind all of these.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for solution and answer @SafaOrhan :)
Now i have build successfully APK.
And thanks for tutorial so i can understand logic behind it.

Comment: It was a pleasure. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

If our application is exceeding more than 64K methods then we need to enable the multiDex in our code.

Add the dependency in build.gradle

```
    dependencies 
    {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    }
```

Enable multidex in build.gradle like the following

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

Now sync your code and run it then it will work.